# Can I develop Sencha Touch app for iOS without a MAC?

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am evaluating HTML 5 framework for mobile platforms. One thing I particularly want to know is that does Sencha Touch still require a MAC to develop iOS app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sencha Touch 2 can develop iOS apps on Windows.  I know many people who are doing it, too.

In their [documentation](http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-touch-quick-start/) they do mention that the most serious drawback of windows development is that you will not be able to use the iOS Simulator

Comment: If I cannot use the iOS Simulator, how do I test the app I built then? On Windows of course

Comment: You can still put them on a device.  (an iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using tools like:

- The [Ripple Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc/related?hl=en) for chrome.
- Also try [iEmu](http://www.iemu.org/index.php/Main_Page), which an ios emulator for windows.
- [iPadian.](http://netmediablog.com/how-to-run-ios-apps-on-pc-with-ipadian)